# Get all shipping classes in a shipping method init - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a custom shipping method following Woocommerce [Shipping Method API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/). In the `init` method of my shipping method class, I'm trying to get all shipping classes using `WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes()`.

This call fails as a PHP fatal error:
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_shipping_classes() on null...*
This suggests that `WC()->shipping` is `null` which is basically an instance of `WC_Shipping` class.

I'm doing similar to Flat rate shipping method of Woocommerce core. The similar code works in the Woocommerce as seen [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/e8cc1076ad6d6f1d3932fb8087689e79f776768d/includes/shipping/flat-rate/includes/settings-flat-rate.php#L41).
Here's my shipping method class:

```
class WCS_City_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate {

    /**
     * Cities applicable on
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    public $cities = array();

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {

        $this->id                 = 'city_shipping';
        $this->instance_id        = absint( $instance_id );
        $this->method_title       = __( 'Flat Rate City Shipping', 'woocommerce-city-shipping' );
        $this->method_description = __( 'Applies only when shipping city matches one of provided.', 'woocommerce-city-shipping' );
        $this->supports           = array( 'shipping-zones', 'instance-settings', );

        $this->init();

        // Save settings
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }


    /**
     * Init.
     *
     * Initialize user set variables.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function init() {
        $this->instance_form_fields = include( 'settings-city-shipping.php' );
        $this->title                = $this->get_option( 'title' );
        $this->tax_status           = $this->get_option( 'tax_status' );
        $this->cities               = $this->get_option( 'cities' );
        $this->cost                 = $this->get_option( 'cost' );
        $this->type                 = $this->get_option( 'type', 'class' );
    }

    /**
     * ... Rest of code
     * 
     */
}
```

And here's `settings-city-shipping.php` which was included in `init` method.

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$shipping_classes = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes(); // Fatal error here
```

The shipping method is added using the filter as:

```
// Add shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', array( $this, 'add_shipping_method_class' ) );
public function add_shipping_method_class( $methods ) {

    if ( class_exists( 'WCS_City_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
        $methods['city_shipping'] = 'WCS_City_Shipping_Method';
    }
    return $methods;

}
```

Please help to find what is causing fatal error and how to get all shipping classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. I had initialized the `WCS_City_Shipping_Method` class in the initialization code of the plugin class for this custom shipping method. The code was running before `Woocommerce` was ready and so causing fatal error.

I had missed this important line from Woocommerce Shipping API [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/):

> To ensure the classes you need to extend exist, you should wrap your
>   class in a function which is called after all plugins are loaded.

Anyways, I solved issue by not initializing the class and wrapping it into a method which runs on `plugins_loaded` action hook. Here are the changes:

```
public function plugins_loaded_action() {
    // Load shipping method class
    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', array( $this, 'wcs_shipping_method' ) );
}

// Placed in plugin class init method
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'plugins_loaded_action' ) );

public function wcs_shipping_method() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-wcs-method.php';
}
```